# CNN-Divide images into training/validation/testing

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science

I'm trying to divide my images (dataset of bunnies and dogs) into `x_train`, `x_val`, `y_train`, `y_val`, and testing.

The following is what I did:

I placed the photos of each class (dogs/bunnies) in separate folders inside two folders: training and testing.

Training directory-> Bunny directory -> bunny images

Training directory-> Puppy directory -> puppy images

Testing directory-> Bunny directory -> bunny images

Testing directory-> Puppy directory -> puppy images

I used the following code to get the images from the folders:

```
training_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./images/train',
                                             target_size = (28, 28),
                                             batch_size = 86,
                                             class_mode = 'binary',
                                             color_mode='rgb',
                                             classes=None)


test_data = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('./images/test',
                                        target_size = (28, 28),
                                        batch_size = 86,
                                        class_mode = 'binary',
                                        color_mode='rgb',
                                        classes=None)
```

Which gives me the following output:

> Found 152 images belonging to 2 classes.
>
> Found 23 images belonging to 2 classes.

Question 1: I wasn't sure how to define my labels here (`y_val`/ `y_train`) or if I need to (but it appears that most models have `y_val`/`y_train`).

Question 2: I tried to run

```
x_train, x_val = train_test_split(training_data, test_size=0.1)
```

In order to at least split my training data into validation/training, but when I tried to run my model it gave me the following error:

```
history=classifier.fit_generator(x_train,
                     steps_per_epoch = (8000 / 86),
                     epochs = 2,
                     validation_data = x_val,
                     validation_steps = 8000/86,
                     callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction])
```

ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`.

> Found: [(array([[[[0.5058095 , 0.46913707, 0.42369673],...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

From my experience there's no discernable confinements in naming y,x variables. For example in [this](https://www.kaggle.com/janiobachmann/patient-charges-clustering-and-regression#Preprocessing%20our%20Data%20and%20using%20Pipelines:) kernel a person uses `y_train, y_test` names for labels and [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/linear_regression_eager_api.py) a person uses `train_Y`. There's a rule that you should give names that shows what the variable is about.

**Question 2:**

I would recommend using `validation_split` parameter  in `ImageDataGenerator` ([doc](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)) to set up fraction of images reserved for validation. After that I would recommend using `subset` parameter in `flow_from_directory` ([doc](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory)) to define `training_generator` and `validation generator` variables.  (I want to point out that the flow_from_directory returns generator, not data).

So your code would look like:

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    validation_split=0.2,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    './images/train',
    target_size = (28, 28),
    batch_size = 86,
    class_mode = 'binary',
    color_mode='rgb',
    classes=None, subset="training"
)

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    './images/train',
    target_size = (28, 28),
    batch_size = 86,
    class_mode = 'binary',
    color_mode='rgb',
    classes=None, subset="validation"
)

history=classifier.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = (8000 / 86),
    epochs = 2,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = 8000/86,
    callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction]
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Any idea how to run a confusion matrix using seaborn.heatmap following my code with the generators?